# ¿Cómo funcionan los aislamientos en transacciones de SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Sé que existen estos niveles de aislamiento en SQL Server:

- Read uncommitted
- Read committed
- Repeatable read
- Serializable
- Snapshot

Y tengo el siguiente código, para cada uno de ellos:

```
set transaction isolation level serializable;

            begin tran                        
                update Table set Field=2
                waitfor delay '00:00:15'                
            commit

set transaction isolation level read commited;

            begin tran                        
                update Table set Field=2
                waitfor delay '00:00:15'                
            commit

set transaction isolation level repeatable read;

            begin tran                        
                update Table set Field=2
                waitfor delay '00:00:15'                
            commit

set transaction isolation level read committed;

            begin tran                        
                update Table set Field=2
                waitfor delay '00:00:15'                
            commit

set transaction isolation level read uncommitted;

            begin tran                        
                update Table set Field=2
                waitfor delay '00:00:15'                
            commit

set transaction isolation level snapshot;

            begin tran                        
                update Table set Field=2
                waitfor delay '00:00:15'                
            commit

--Siempre en paralelo ejecuto sentencias como estas:

select * from Table
delete from Table where Field=1
insert into Table (Field) values ('Data')
update from Table where Field =3
```

Y todas ellas se ejecutan después de que cada transacción terminó con su respectivo nivel de aislamiento.

¿Cómo diferencio su funcionamiento uno de otro si siempre obtengo el mismo resultado?

Comment: Si solo es una sentencia en paralelo, no vas a poder notar las diferencias. Deberías ejecutar sentencias DML y `SELECT` a una de las tablas que es afectada por una transacción pesada que se ejecuta en paralelo para poder notar los cambios.

Comment: ¡Has leído este [artículo](https://technet.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms189122(v=sql.105).aspx)?

Comment: Desgraciadamente, una de las mejores explicaciones por parte de Microsoft se encuentra sólo en inglés [aquí](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/tn-archive/cc546518(v=technet.10)). Además del [compendio de artículos de Brent Ozar](https://www.brentozar.com/isolation-levels-sql-server/)

Answer (score 1):

Hola aca comparto algunas ideas que pueden ser de utilidad

**Read Uncommitted:**

Las transacciones que corren a este nivel no manejan bloqueos compartidos(Shared Locks) para evitar que otras transacciones modifiquen los datos que fueron leidos en transaction actual. Ademas las transacciones no son bloqueadas por los lock exclusivos en el momento que la data esta siendo modificada. Esto permite que otras transacciones puedan leer la data modificada cuando esta no ha completado el commit.

Ejemplo:
Valor inicial: Field = 1
set transaction isolation level read uncommitted;

Transaccion1 es iniciada:

```
 BEGIN TRAN                        
            UPDATE Table
            SET Field=2
             WHERE Field2 = 10
            …
```

Transaccion1 continua mientras Transaccion 2 es iniciada y el commit es completado:

```
BEGIN TRAN                        
            SELECT FIELD
            FROM Table
            WHERE Field2 = 10
        COMMIT
```

Transaccion1 es completada y el commit es finalizado.
                …

```
    UPDATE Table
            SET Field= 3
             WHERE Field2 = 10
  COMMIT
```

**Read Committed:**
Con Read Committed las transacciones manejan un lock exclusivo en el momento que los datos estan siendo modificados, por lo tanto no permite que otras transacciones lean los datos modificados hasta que  en la transaction no se haya completado el commit. Este tipo de data aislamiento prevee el problema conocido como Dirty Read(Lectura sucia, cuando lees una data que fue modificada, por lo tanto ya no son los valores reales). Pero los datos pueden modificarse por otras transacciones entre sentencias individuales con la transaccion que esta en proceso, esto trae como resultado a Non-Repeatable Read o una Fila Fantasma.

El comportamiento de READ COMMITTED esta definido por la configuracion del  READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT opcion en la base de datos.

Ejemplo1:
 El comportamiento es similar al ejemplo anterior porque la opcion READ_COMMITED_SNAPSHOT esta en off por defecto.

Ejemplo2:

```
ALTER DATABASE <DB Name>
SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON
```

Usando el ejemplo anterior, la Transaccion 2 es ejecutada despues que las Transaccion 1, el valor de Field fue modificado a 2 en el primer UPDATE, despues el valor es modificado nuevamente a 3 en el final de la transaccion 1, por lo tanto el valor con se hace el COMMIT es 3.

La sentencia SELECT en la transaccion 2 no espera a que la Transaccion 1 sea completada, por lo tanto devuelve el ultimo valor Committed, que es 1.

**Repeatable Read:**

En este caso, las sentencias no pueden leer datos que, han sido modificados sin haber sido Committed, por otras transactions hasta que la transaccion inicial no ha sido completada.
Los Shared Locks(Bloqueos compartidos) son inicialidados para todos los datos que esten siendo leidos  en la transaccion, y se van a mantener bloqueados hasta que la operacion sea completada. Esto garantiza que otras transacciones no puedan modicar filas que han estan siendo leidas/modificadas en la transaccion actual. Este nivel de aislamiento evita el problema conocido como Non-Repeatable Read.

Ahora otras transacciones pueden agregar nuevas filas, pero si las nuevas filas coinciden con las condiciones de busqueda de la transaccion inicial, estas nuevas filas van a ser leidas por la transaction actual y eso es lo que se conoce como Phantom Reads.

**Serializable:**

En este nivel de aislamiento de los datos, las sentencias no pueden leer datos que han sido modificados por otras transacciones sin haber sido completados. Ademas otras transaciones no van a poder modicar datos que esta siendo leidos por la transaction actual hasta que sea completada, de la misma manera otras transacciones no van a poder inserter nuevas filas que contengan valores y/o llaves que esten en el rango de busqueda de la transaccion actual hasta que esta halla sido completada.

**Snapshot Isolation:**

En este caso, los datos leidos por cada sentencia  en una transaccion van a ser una version consistente transaccional que existian al comienzo de la transaccion. Cualquier modificacion hecha a estos datos por otras transacciones despues de iniciada la transaction actual no van a ser visible. Este nivel de aislamiento de datos no realiza bloqueo de lectura, no limita otras transaciones de modificar los datos.
La opcion ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION en la base de datos debe estar On antes de iniciar la transaccion.

```
ALTER DATABASE <DB Name>
SET ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION ON
```

Espero le sea de utilidad la explicacion.

Answer (score 0):

Los niveles de aislamiento por sí solos no hacen nada a menos que haya una competencia de recursos. Vamos a suponer que hay un registro / página / tabla bloqueada y vos queres leerlo:

- Con `read committed` no vas a poder hasta que no se termine el commit;
- Con `read uncommitted` lo leerás pero de forma sucia;
- `Serializable` te permite que al hacer un SELECT dentro de una transacción se bloqueen de forma exclusiva los registros.

¡Y así con el resto! Creo que te hace falta una lectura básica de bases de datos relacionales.

Comment: La respuesta parece correcta, pero deberías añadir la descripción de los dos niveles de aislamiento que te faltan (repeatable read y snapshot) en lugar de poner "_y así con el resto_".